# Question about equivalent relationship n polygon and regularity of degree 2

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In combinatorics, I found that it is regarded as trivial that a grpaph is n polygon is equivalent to the fact that the graph is finite connected  graph that is regular of degree 2.

I am wondering is there any direct ways of proving the fact that if the graph is finite connected  graph that is regular of degree 2, then it is n-polygon, without using subsequent theorems such as how tree is defined?(because I am thinking about using this theorem to prove that finite connected grapes with n vetex and n-1 edges is tree) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: Calculate the number of edges in a finite connected graph that is regular of degree 2 of $n$ vertices. Then consider a graph with one less edge, and what kind of special shape it must have to satisfy the known vertex degrees. Then add the edge back and observe what the final shape must be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! Yes, I have thought of using tree to prove this theorem, however, the reason why I am asking this question is because I want to use this conclusion to prove that n-1edges graph is a tree. With that purpose, I am afraid I shouldn't use any subsequent theorem to prove this one…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a graph with $n$ vertices, every vertex has degree $2$, and it is connected.

Start with just the vertices, no edges, and consider one vertex $A$. It has $2$ degrees to satisfy. Let's put one edge on $A$. Now the other end of this edge must go somewhere. It could loop back to $A$, forming a self-loop. But then all of $A$'s degrees get satisfied, meaning it can't connect to any other vertices. However, the graph overall must be connected, meaning $A$ must have an edge to another vertex. Let's call this $B$.

Now $B$ is in a similar situation as $A$ was before: one degree satisfied, one remaining. And like before, the remaining degree cannot loop back to either $A$ or $B$. So it goes to a new vertex $C$. Keep going like this till the last vertex. At this point, the $n-2$ vertices in between are fully satisfied, and only $A$ and the $n^{th}$ vertices have unfulfilled degrees: 1 each. So they must connect together, completing the stipulated graph.

Looking at what we did, we made a linear chain of vertices, and connected it back to the beginning. So a circle. But if you visualize the graph with vertices as points and edges as equal-length line segments, you get an $n$-polygon